# Google API Client GTMHTTPUploadFetcher duplicated

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, google-api-client

I'm creating a cocoapod. To .podspec I've added the line:

```
cs.dependency 'Google-API-Client', '~> 1.0'
```

and since this moment I can't push my framework to spec repo. During

```
pod repo push company-private MyFramework.podspec --allow-warnings --verbose
```

I can see following problem:

```
ERROR | [MyFramework/Core]  Google-API-Client/Source/Objects/GTLService.m:86:1: error: duplicate interface definition for class 'GTMHTTPUploadFetcher'
```

I have no idea how to fix it. Tried:

```
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/
sudo rm -fr Pods/
```

But this didn't help. It seems to be Google-API-Client bug, but their time to response is so huge (waiting ~6months for previous ticket, still not solved), that I can't wait so long. Anyone have any idea how to skip the problem? Building locally on my machine does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working already, just need to bump the version to `Google-API-Client (1.0.422)`

Comment: I'm having the same [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33581805/1077789). Although I'm installing the pod, not creating one. I have that same version of the `Google-API-Client` but unfortunately I still get that error. This is so frustrating. After all this time, this issue still hasn't been resolved by Google!