# Duplicate interface definition for class 'GTMHTTPUploadFetcher'

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, cocoapods

I plan to use [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/) in my Swift project. I'm trying to add the Drive SDK via CocoaPods (v0.39.0). Below is my Podfile.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Google-API-Client/Drive'
```

I have the `use_frameworks!` flag added so that CocoaPods can convert Objective-C pods to Swift frameworks instead of static libraries.

Pod installation is successful. However when I build the project, I get the following error.

**Duplicate interface definition for class 'GTMHTTPUploadFetcher'**

Deleting DerivedData folder and cleaning the project didn't  work.

I also tried without adding the `use_frameworks!` and then adding the library via a bridging header way. That works without an issue. The thing is all my other dependencies work with it turned on. And unfortunately CocoaPods [doesn't](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3839) [support](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3317) turning that flag for certain pods only.

Is there a workaround to resolve this issue?

---

As stated in Google's [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/support), Google engineers supposedly monitor questions tagged with google-drive-sdk so I hope at least they'll see this and fix it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same problem. My solution was to *not install* the Google API Client for iOS using CocoaPods because I was using Swift-based pods and I, therefore, could not remove `use_frameworks!` to attempt to get around the duplicate header issue.

I instead installed the library manually by following the detailed instructions at https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart?ver=swift for Steps 2, 3, and 4. I followed the instructions but applied them to *my existing workspace* instead of creating a new workspace.

It's important to note that I had to adjust the paths in **User Header Search Paths** to match the locations where I actually copied the source code from Google.

I'm copying the instructions here for reference.

> **Step 2: Download the Google Client Library**
>
> Run the following commands to download the library using git:
>
> - `git clone https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client.git`
> - `git clone https://github.com/google/gtm-oauth2.git`
> - `git clone https://github.com/google/gtm-session-fetcher.git`
> - `git clone https://github.com/stig/json-framework.git -b v2.3`
> - `cp -R gtm-oauth2/Source google-api-objectivec-client/Source/OAuth2`
> - `cp -R json-framework/Classes google-api-objectivec-client/Source/JSON`
>
> **Step 3: Prepare the workspace**
>
> Open Xcode and create a new workspace named "Quickstart".
>   Using File > Add Files to "Quickstart"..., add the following projects to the workspace from the libraries you cloned in the previous step:
>
> - google-api-objectivec-client/Source/GTL.xcodeproj
> - gtm-session-fetcher/Source/GTMSessionFetcher.xcodeproj
>
> Select the "GTMSessionFetcher" project and make the following changes:
>
> - Add a new target of the type iOS > Framework & Library> Cocoa Touch Static Library and name it "GTMSessionFetcherLib".
> - Add all of the .m files in the project's GTMSessionFetcher group to the target's Build Phases > Compile Sources section.
>
> Select the "GTL" project's "GTLTouchStaticLib" target and make the following changes:
>
> - Add the library GTMSessionFetcher/libGTMSessionFetcherLib.a to Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries.
> - Add the absolute path to gtm-session-fetcher/Source/ to Build Settings > User Header Search Paths.
> - Add the flag GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER=1 to Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros.
> - Delete the "GTL" project's "GTLFramework" target.
> - In the Project navigator, delete GTL project's GTL Source > Common > HTTPFetcher group.
>
> **Step 4: Prepare the project**
>
> - Create a new iOS > Application > Single View Application project named "QuickstartApp". Set the Language to Swift , and when saving the project set the Add to and Group fields to "Quickstart".
> - Add the following frameworks and libraries to the project's Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries section:
>     libGTLTouchStaticLib.a
>
>   - Security.framework
>   - SystemConfiguration.framework
> - Change the following Build Settings:
> - Add -ObjC -all_load to Other Linker Flags.
> - Add the absolute path to the following directories to User Header Search Paths:
>
>   - gtm-session-fetcher/Source/
>   - google-api-objectivec-client/Source/**
> - Add the flag GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER=1 to Preprocessor Macros.
> - Add the file google-api-objectivec-client/Source/OAuth2/Touch/GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib to the project's Supporting Files group.
> - Add the following files to the QuickstartApp group:
>
>   - google-api-objectivec-client/Source/Services/Drive/Generated/GTLDrive_Sources.m
>   - google-api-objectivec-client/Source/Services/Drive/Generated/GTLDrive.h
> - If not created automatically, create a new header file Bridging-Header.h with the following content:
>
>   - `#import "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"`
>   - `#import "GTLDrive.h"`
> - Set Build Settings > Objective-C Bridging Header to the absolute path of the bridging header.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just gave it a try and it works. Although it doesn't fix the original issue, since it works, I'm gonna accept it for the time being. Thank you. I can't believe Google is neglecting this. It's an issue that's been around for months!

Comment: Thanks @Isuru. I couldn't believe how complicated it was to install. I'm sure it will be easier once they revise the code and your original issue may even be fixed. It's been a longstanding issue, like you said.

Comment: Yeah. It's ridiculously complicated. I expect a little more support from Google for distributing their iOS SDKs since they explicitly said they'll use CocoaPods as the main channel.

Comment: @Daniel :-  "Select the "GTL" project's "GTLTouchStaticLib" target and make the following changes:

Add the library GTMSessionFetcher/libGTMSessionFetcherLib.a to Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries." i am not finding that  GTMSessionFetcher/libGTMSessionFetcherLib.a , please elaborate on this issue !

Comment: @dip The `GTLTouchStaticLib` **target** should be available under the `GTL` project inside your project. The `libGTMSessionFetcherLib.a` comes from the `GTMSessionFetcher` **project** inside your project. I know it's a difficult install, but the directions provided by Google are valid.

Comment: yes @Daniel, i followed instructions as mentioned on google site, but this line mentioned by you "Select the "GTL" project's "GTLTouchStaticLib" target and make the following changes:" i am not finding any "GTLTouchStaticLib" target under GTL project ! :(

Comment: where can I find the GTLTouchStaticLib in GTLCore.xcodeproj?

Comment: I am not finding it either :(

Answer (score 4):

According to Google this error is caused by using a cocoapod by a third party, but they now have an official pod in the project (https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/blob/master/GoogleAPIClient.podspec) and the problem should be fixed.

See: https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/103

Use:

`pod 'GoogleAPIClient/Drive', '~> 1.0'`

and probably also:

`pod 'GTMOAuth2'` or `pod 'Google/SignIn'`

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found was that you have to go into those three projects that Google Drive imports and check how the imports are done. Right now its importing headers, not frameworks (the three frameworks depend on each other). You have to just do it manually and it'll work.

I don't have code samples to show you but I know I got it to work last time in this fashion.

Comment: By [three projects](http://i.imgur.com/i34BYio.png), do you mean `Google-API-Client`, `gtm-http-fetcher` and `gtm-oauth2`?

Comment: Or do you mean adding them manually in the [`Podfile`](http://pastie.org/10540347)? I tried that too but still get the same error.

Comment: @isurur did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I mean those three projects. You can edit the projects directly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution here:

Go to edit scheme -> Select Build -> Build option untick the Parallelize Build

Now run your App